# How to link event logic to Bootstrap 5 dropdown clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How do you attach an "onclick" event to a [Bootstrap 5 dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#events) so you can perform application logic according to which dropdown menu item was clicked?

The docs explain how to receive events when the dropdown is open and closed, but there doesn't appear to be any way to find the clicked menu item. I even tried attaching a jQuery click event to the menu items, but that appears to be blocked.

My dropdown looks like:

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="tuningSelectButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Tuning
  </button>
  <ul id="tuning-options" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="tuningSelectButton">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tuning="value1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tuning="value2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-tuning="value3">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and my Javascript looks like:

```
$('#tuning-options li a').change(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    console.log(el.val())
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all, you're listening for `change` events on `<a>` elements. [Change events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) are only fired on form elements (`<input>`s, `<textarea>`s and `<select>`s), when their native `value` attribute changes value. Links do not have a native `value` attribute, therefore `change` is never fired on them.
   jQuery documentation for [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) also states form elements are the only valid targets for this event.
   For the same reason, running jQuery's [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) on an `<a>` will always return an empty string (I would have guessed `undefined`. Still falsey value).
2. Looking for a more suitable event to listen to, found this in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#events):

> `hide.bs.dropdown` and `hidden.bs.dropdown` events have a `clickEvent` property (only when the original Event type is `click`) that contains an Event Object for the click event.

3. Last, but not least, Bootstrap dropdown relies on its markup (HTML structure). In particular, both `.dropdown-toggle` and `.dropdown-menu` should be wrapped in a `.dropdown` element. Bootstrap uses it as dropdown events emitter.
   Additionally, you should move `tuning-options` id from `.dropdown-menu` to the wrapper.

At which point this code will work:

```
$('#tuning-options').on('hide.bs.dropdown', ({ clickEvent }) => {
  if (clickEvent?.target) {
    console.log($(clickEvent.target).data('tuning'))
  }
})
```

---

Working example:

```js
$('#tuning-options').on('hide.bs.dropdown', ({ clickEvent }) => {
  if (clickEvent?.target) {
    console.log($(clickEvent.target).data('tuning'))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown" id="tuning-options">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dmb1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Select tuning
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dmb1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-tuning="value1" href="#">Tuning 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-tuning="value2" href="#">Tuning 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-tuning="value3" href="#">Tuning 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Additional note:** Although the specs indicate this code should only work for `click` events, it also works when a dropdown menu item is selected using a keyboard (most likely Bootstrap fires a programmatic `click` event when a dropdown menu item is selected by keyboard).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with vanilla js as well

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    const myDropdown = document.getElementById('dmb1')
    myDropdown.addEventListener('hide.bs.dropdown', event => {
        console.log(event.clickEvent.path[0].getAttribute('value'))
    })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="dropdown" id="tuning-options">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dmb1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Select tuning
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dmb1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" value="value1" href="#">Tuning 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" value="value2" href="#">Tuning 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" value="value3" href="#">Tuning 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the value in `data-tuning` then you should change

```
console.log(el.val())
```

into

```
console.log(el.data('tuning'))
```

Check out JQuery's API Documentation to learn more.
https://api.jquery.com/data/